# JS Objects and Functions Corrections

Tags: javascript, html

I've got a homework assignment to correct some Javascript code that is preventing functions from being executed. I've corrected everything I can find, even used JSFiddle and JSHint to make sure. So there's no syntax errors left, but there must be a logic error because nothing is working. I'd appreciate a quick look at my code, I'm sure it's a minor issue that I'm just overlooking. Thanks!

(There's bound to be some messy code here with how many things I've tried to change around, apologies for that).

First the very basic HTML:

```
<body>
<p id="message"></p>
<p id="movies"></p>
<p id="object"></p>
</body>
```

Then the JS:

```
// Define variables
var output = document.getElementById("message");
var BR = "<br>";
var makeBreakfast;
var mood;
var energyLevel;
var doWork;
var powerOn;
var command;
var duration;
var quitWork;

// Define robot object
var robot = {
material: "titanium",
mood: "happy",
energyLevel: 100,
powerOn: false,
command: "Sweeping the floor",
duration: 10,
favoriteMovies: ["2001: A Space Odyssey", "The Terminator", "I, Robot",        "WALL-E", "Short Circuit", "Forbidden Planet"]
};


makeBreakfast = function (newMood) {
mood = newMood;
if (mood === "Happy") {
    output.innerHTML += "Here are your waffles and milk, master." + BR;
} else {
    output.innerHTML += "Here is your burnt toast and lukewarm water,    master." + BR;
    energyLevel = 50;
}
};
doWork = function () {
if (!powerOn) {
    powerOn = true;
    output.innerHtml += "My current task is: " + command + ". Duration: " +     duration + " minutes." + BR;
}
};
quitWork = function () {
if (powerOn) {
    energyLevel = 90;
    powerOn = false;
    command = "Taking a nap";
}
};

// Make robot do housework
doWork();
quitWork();
```

The full assignment is as follows:
1) Correct the code, and make doWork and quitWork execute properly.
2) Call the makeBreakfast argument and use the string "mad" as the argument.
3) Add a new method and call it to display a string (left this part out, not helpful right now)
4) List all of the robots favorite movies, each on a new line.
5) Use named indexing syntax to add a new property called language to the robot object. Initialize it with the language of your choice.
6) Using named indexing syntax, loop through the object and list each of the property and value pairs on a new line. Display the results in a new paragraph.

I really only wanted help with #1, but if seeing the full assignment helps, this is it. Thanks everyone!

Comment: You REALLY need to describe what the code is supposed to accomplish.  What is the goal of the assignment.

Comment: @jfriend00 Apologies, I thought I explained it. It's really quite simple, just need to make those two functions doWork and quitWork, work. As-is my code did nothing. Basically just need to make those functions do what they are designed to do and display their messages on the page. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @humble.rumble Maybe I should have listed the WHOLE assignment, but I didn't really want help with all of it, just this portion. So there is some code in here that applies to the next steps of the assignment. But step one was just to correct 20+ errors and get the doWork and quitWork to execute. I'll add in all of the directions for reference, but I really don't want help with the rest of it. Thanks for everything!

Comment: @humble.rumble yes your code adjustments are working for me! Thank you! I edited my original post to show the full assignment if you would like to look over it anyways. Thanks again!

Comment: @humble.rumble Actually now that I'm looking at this closer, it appears that the makeBreakfast function executes, but I never see anything from the doWork or quitWork functions.

Comment: @humble.rumble Checked my book and the setTimeout is WAY further along than we are currently and the callbacks I can't even find. Is there a way to do it without adding code that I haven't learned yet? Sorry to keep bugging you, just trying to figure this out. It should be something very simple since this is an introductory class that we are only a few weeks into (Javascript at least). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to make it an object, and tell the poor schmuck to make you breakfast!

([Full Difference](https://www.diffchecker.com/kvrzwtgf))

```js
// Define variables
var output = document.getElementById("message");
var movies = document.getElementById("movies");
// Define variables
var output = document.getElementById("message");
var movies = document.getElementById("movies");
var object = document.getElementById("object");
var BR = "<br>";

// Define robot object
var robot = {
    material: "titanium",
    mood: "Happy",
    energyLevel: 100,
    powerOn: false,
    command: "Sweeping the floor",
    duration: 10,
    favoriteMovies: ["2001: A Space Odyssey", "The Terminator", "I, Robot", "WALL-E", "Short Circuit", "Forbidden Planet"],
    
    makeBreakfast: function (newMood) {
        if(newMood) this.mood = newMood;
        this.command = "Making breakfast";
        this.doWork();
        if (this.mood === "Happy") {
            output.innerHTML += "Here are your waffles and milk, master." + BR;
        } else {
            output.innerHTML += "Here is your burnt toast and lukewarm water,    master." + BR;
            this.energyLevel = 50;
        }
    },
    doWork: function () {
        if(!this.powerOn) {
            this.powerOn = true;
            output.innerHTML += "My current task is: " + this.command + ". Duration: " + this.duration + " minutes." + BR;
        }
    },
    quitWork: function () {
        if (this.powerOn) {
            this.energyLevel = 90;
            this.powerOn = false;
            this.command = "Taking a nap";
            output.innerHTML += "My current task is: " + this.command + ". Duration: " + this.duration + " minutes." + BR;
        }
    }
};

// Make robot do housework
robot.doWork();
robot.quitWork();
robot.makeBreakfast();
robot.quitWork();
robot.makeBreakfast("Mad");
robot.quitWork();
```

```html
<body>
    <p id="message"></p>
    <p id="movies"></p>
    <p id="object"></p>
</body>
```